# dynamically adding input type when we will select an option from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project for attendance management. I have one drop-down box where months are enlisted. I want to implement that when I will click on any month then the dynamically buttons will be added in division. Lets suppose I have selected January month from drop-down box then 31 buttons will be added in division and vice versa.

Following is the code from my HTML

```js
var counterButton = 0;

function addAllInputs(divName, inputType) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    
    switch(inputType) {
        case 'January':
            for(i=0;i<31;i++)
            {
                newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counterText + 1) + " <br><input type='button' name='myInputs[]'>";
                counterText++;
            }               
            break;

        case 'February':
            for(i=0;i<28;i++)
            {
                newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counterText + 1) + " <br><input type='button' name='myInputs[]'>";
                counterText++;
            }               
            break;

        case 'March':
            for(i=0;i<31;i++)
            {
                newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counterText + 1) + " <br><input type='button' name='myInputs[]'>";
                counterText++;
            }               
            break;

        case 'April':
            for(i=0;i<30;i++)
            {
                newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counterText + 1) + " <br><input type='button' name='myInputs[]'>";
                counterText++;
            }               
            break;
    }
    
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="" >January</option>
      <option value="">February</option>
      <option value="">March</option>
      <option value="">April</option>
      <option value="">May</option>
      <option value="">June</option>
      <option value="">July</option>
      <option value="">September</option>
      <option value="">October</option>
      <option value="">November</option>
      <option value="">December</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to listen for the `change` event on the `select` element, and then call your function on `change`, something like this:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    addAllInputs(divName,inputType);
});
```